# Bootstrap does not be set to Django app

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap does not be set to my Django app.In google console,Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) bootflat.min.css error happens.I wrote in settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG =True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'bootflat.github.io'), ]
```

in PythonServer_nginx.conf

```
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name MyServerIPAdress; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/PythonServer/PythonServer/accounts/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/PythonServer/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

I do not know why Bootstrap does not be set to my Django app.I run command python manage.py collectstatic but no error happens.How should I fix this?What should I write it?

Comment: Why are you appending an url to what is meant to be set as dirs in `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Comment: You should show your app directory structure. Where is bootstrap located in your app's directories?

Answer (score 9):

I assume the project works fine in local, this problem occurs only when you use nginx. If that is the case probably the path you mentioned in the nginx config for **location /static** is wrong, try getting the absolute path to the static folder from the server and see.

Answer (score 5):

I have no way to test my answer for obvious reason, but your `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` don't match. If you change your `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"/static/"),'https://bootflat.github.io']`, it might work. I suggested so because it doesn't make sense to me to `os.path.join` a local path with a public URL.

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` don't need to match, the first is meant to add other dirs beside the second.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,
In settings.py:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
```

Now at last, add these lines:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
```

Now, put all your bootstrap files in a 'static' folder under your project folder.

At your HTML code, 
You have to load the static files using:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Now,you can use your static files using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
```

P.s. my 'bootstrap.min.css' is present under 'static' folder and then 'assets' and then 'css' folder.

It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

First: where are you storing your static bootstrap files? I recommend storing them in the app's directory where you are referencing them in a template. For example, if you have an app `myapp` I would put them in `/myapp/static/myapp/`. So if I'm storing `bootstrap.css` it would go in `/myapp/static/myapp/bootstrap.css`.

Next, in your template you need to reference the correct static folder. For the Bootstrap stylesheet, the `href` would look like `href = "{% static 'myapp/bootstrap.css' }%"`

Lastly, in your `settings.py` file add the line `STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/PythonServer/PythonServer/accounts/static'` (based on what you wrote, just make sure that it's pointing to the correct deployment folder where you're keeping your live static files) and run `collectstatic` again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need `STATICFILES_DIRS` since django will collect static files for you from each `INSTALLED_APP` specified in your `settings.py`. You need to add `bootstrap4` to `INSTALLED_APP`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'my_great_app',
    'bootstrap4',
]
```

You need to specify `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` as you do in your `settings.py`. You need to understand why you use each setting.

- Django uses `STATIC_ROOT` in collect_static command which collects
  all static files from apps and directories in `STATICFILES_DIRS` puts
  in `STATIC_ROOT`. For example you created a new app which has it's
  required static files in itself, you run `./manage.py collect_static`
  to put your static files in `STATIC_ROOT` in which web server (nginx
  in your case) serves them. At your installation `STATIC_ROOT` should be
  showing to `/home/ubuntu/PythonServer/PythonServer/accounts/static`
  as seen in your nginx config.
- `STATIC_URL` is used to create static file urls when you use
  `static` template tag. Since the files are served by nginx you need a
  specific path, host etc.
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` is used to add static files which are not residing
  in apps folders. I do no recommend its use for your case.

On your template you need to use something like the following:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap4/bootstrap4.html' %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}
{# Display a form #}

<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Taken from [django-bootstrap4 github repo](https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4).

By extending `bootstrap4/bootstrap4.html` you would get required css and js files in your html. With `{% load bootstrap4 %}` you can use bootstrap4 templatetags and filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding following code in your **url.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += patterns('', (
    r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
    'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}
))
```

Add static root variable in **settings.py** as shown by *Luke B*

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/PythonServer/PythonServer/accounts/static'
```

Check here documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/